# How properly to add a password to programmatically created PDF in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

Currently I'm creating my PDF in the next way:

```
func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
    let data = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: A4PageHeight, height: A4PageWidth), nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: 0, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return data
}
```

by using Page Renderer:

```
let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()
let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: self.getHTML())
printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
```

and try to create the PDF from data as:

```
let pdfData = printPageRenderer.drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer)
mailComposer.addAttachmentData(pdfData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "My PDF")
```

When I'm creating a new instance for my Page Renderer:

```
class CustomPrintPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {
let A4PageWidth: CGFloat = 595.2
let A4PageHeight: CGFloat = 841.8

var html: String?

override init() {
    super.init()

    // Specify the frame of the A4 page.
    let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: A4PageHeight, height: A4PageWidth)

    // Set the page frame.
    self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "paperRect")

    // Set the horizontal and vertical insets (that's optional).
    self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "printableRect")
    self.setValue(1234, forKey: kCGPDFContextUserPassword as String)
    self.setValue(1234, forKey: kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as String)
}
```

I'm trying to set password to it via:

```
self.setValue(1234, forKey: kCGPDFContextUserPassword as String)
self.setValue(1234, forKey: kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as String)
```

but when I run my code it crashes with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:  
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key kCGPDFContextUserPassword.'
```

What do I do wrong and how can I fix it? I was googling but could not find anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`, the last parameter is a dictionary that takes the same auxiliary keys as used by `CGPDFContext`.

`kCGPDFContextUserPassword` and `kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword` are among those auxiliary keys.

So it would seem you need to set the password in your call to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`.

```
let info: [AnyHashable: Any] = [kCGPDFContextUserPassword as String : "1234", kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as String : "1234"]
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: A4PageHeight, height: A4PageWidth), info)
```